# Detect selected row with force touch watchkit

Tags: watchkit, selected, watchos-2, wkinterfacetable, force-touch

Is it possible to detect selected row index with force touch? Did force touch in tableView current row is highlighted. But i can't take info about him when context menu appears. TableView method -didSelectRowAtIndex: not called with this event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can handle programmatically with the Force Touch is the [Context Menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Menus.html) and this menu is associated with a specific controller, more information you will find following the link.

About the row highlighting: When you start tapping the system doesn't know what the real action is - the regular touch or the force one. So it is starting to highlight a specific area and only later find out what was the action.

Comment: @IvanNovikov - If my answer was helpful and solved your problem please mark it as acceptable. If you need any additional information not related to the question you can find my contact info on the github page. In any other case it's prohibited by the community rules to move a discussion out of the stackoverflow thus living a question without an answer for the rest of community.